# Button that has 1.04% chance to lead to Page A and 98.96% chance to lead to Page B? -JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I'm trying to create a button that when pressed has a 1.04% chance to lead to Page A and a 98.96% chance to lead to Page B. That's my overall goal but the specific aspect I'm having trouble on is the randomization of the results. I'm quite new to javascript so I apologize in advance. Any help is appreciated.

--edit--
I'm incorporating this code into a Wix project and here is the total code I have so far. I started with easy whole numbers 40/60 to make sure I could do it but the smaller percent I'm having trouble incorporating. It's important I have a decimal percentage 1.04 and not 1.00.

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
let random = 0,counter40 = 0,counter60 = 0;

$w.onReady(function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    if (random <= 40)   {
        counter40++;
    } else {
        counter60++;
     }
  }
  console.log("counter40: " + counter40.toString());
  console.log("counter60: " + counter60.toString());
});

export function button1_click(event) {
    random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    if (random <= 40)   {
        wixLocation.to("/pageB");
    } else {
        wixLocation.to("/pageC");
   }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Well I'm incorporating this aspect into a wix website (which is a whole other thing) but I've updated my question with the code I have so far

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ys84pu6a/1/

HTML:

```
<button id="randomRedirect">
  Press me
</button>
```

JS:

```
let button = document.getElementById('randomRedirect')
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let d = Math.random();
  if (d < 0.9896)
    window.location.href = "pageB.html";
  else
    window.location.href = "pageA.html";
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Math.random()` function. It returns a random number between 0 and 1.
You could use it this way:

```js
x = Math.random()
if(x < 0.0104){//1.04% chance
  window.location.href = [Page A]
}
else{
  window.location.href = [Page B]
}
```

Comment: We generally don't answer poor questions that don't confirm to the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (i.e no attempt at a solution made and posted).

Answer (score 0):

The function that provides pseudo-random values is [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

It returns a floating-point number between 0 and 1.

To get a 1.04% chance, you could simply do this:

```
let pageAChance = Math.random() <= 0.0104;
```